# Dispatch Resize event from trigger in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In wordpress I need to dispatch a resize window event after a gallery has loaded it's images. Inside the gallery plugin there's this trigger:

```
$(document).trigger(‘woocommerce_gallery_images_loaded’);
```

I tried using the trigger in functions.php to dispatch the Resize event:

```
function wpcom_javascript() {
    ?>
    <script>
        
        jQuery(document).on('woocommerce_gallery_images_loaded', function() {
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        });
        
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'wpcom_javascript');
```